# Schedule Crime Case After lunch

Tags: algorithm

Working on Consultant Appointment System. There are many ad-hoc appointments booked online with out specifying the visiting time, but duration. However the consultant will visit customer on Saturday and Sunday between 9 A.M - 1 P.M and 2 P.M to 5 P.M.

The online ad hoc request will specify Reason and Duration. I need to write a code for scheduling these requests, so Consultant can login and see the scheduled items and send it to clients

> The problem is if i found any request duration that exceeds the lunch,
>   i need to ignore in loop and check for next request with small
>   duration. I am not sure how can i skip for time being and process next
>   time(After noon schedule).

John Divorce problem 60min

Kumar land issue 100min

Discussion with Ram 60 min

Crime case `45min`

Local settlement 15min

In the below code i need to skip Crime case as it exceeds lunch time and schedule Local settlement. **Still i need to schedule Crime case after lunch. How can i make this?**

```
 public class OnlineRequest
 {
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public short Duration { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
 }

    public static string LUNCH_TIME = "1:00 P.M";
    public static string END_OF_DAY = "6:00 P.M";


   public static Dictionary<String, List<String>>
              GetSchedules(List<OnlineRequest> requests)
    {
        List<string> schedules = new List<string>();

        DateTime visitStartTime = DateTime.MinValue.Date.AddHours(9);

        int day = 1;
        List<String> eventTimeStr = new List<String>();
        Dictionary<String, List<String>> consultantData 
              = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();
        //Here is the problem
        DateTime eventTime = visitStartTime;
        foreach (OnlineRequest req in requests)
        {
            req.StartTime = eventTime;
            string flag = getTimeDiff(req);
            if (flag.Equals(LUNCH_TIME))
            {
                eventTimeStr.Add(flag + ": LUNCH");
                eventTime = eventTime.AddMinutes(60);
            }
            else if (flag.Equals(END_OF_DAY))
            {
                eventTimeStr.Add(flag + ": GO HOME EOD");

                consultantData.Add(("Day_" + day), eventTimeStr);
                eventTimeStr = new List<String>();

                eventTime = visitStartTime;
                ++day;
            }
            else
            {
                eventTimeStr.Add(eventTime.ToString("h:mm tt") + ": " + req.Reason);
                eventTime = req.EndTime;
            }
        }
        consultantData.Add(("Day_" + day), eventTimeStr);
        return consultantData;
    }    

private static String getTimeDiff(OnlineRequest req)
    {

        DateTime startEventTime = req.StartTime;
        DateTime finishEventTime = req.StartTime.AddMinutes(req.Duration);

        DateTime visitEndTime = DateTime.MinValue.Date.AddHours(17);

        DateTime visitLunchStartTime = DateTime.MinValue.Date.AddHours(12);


        if (finishEventTime.CompareTo(visitLunchStartTime) == 0 && 
                 startEventTime.CompareTo(visitLunchStartTime) > 0)
        {
            return LUNCH_TIME;
        }
        else if (startEventTime.CompareTo(visitLunchStartTime) == 0 && 
                   finishEventTime.CompareTo(visitLunchStartTime) > 0)
        {
            return LUNCH_TIME;
        }
        else if (startEventTime.CompareTo(visitLunchStartTime) < 0 && 
               finishEventTime.CompareTo(visitLunchStartTime) > 0)
        {
            return LUNCH_TIME;
        }
        if (visitEndTime.CompareTo(finishEventTime) < 0)
        {
            return END_OF_DAY;
        }

        req.EndTime = finishEventTime;
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Put more of your own work into this. [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this (very crappy pseudo-code):

```
morning = new Block(3*60, 9);
foreach (OnlineRequest req) {
    if (req.Duration < morning.getFreeTime()) {
        morning.add(req);
    }
}

afternoon = new Block(3*60, 13);
foreach (OnlineRequest req not in morning.requests) {
    if (req.Duration < afternoon.getFreeTime()) {
        afternoon.add(req);
    }
}


foreach (OnlineRequest req in morning.requests ) {
    print(morning.getStartTime(req))
}

foreach (OnlineRequest req in afternoon.requests ) {
    print(afternoon.getStartTime(req))
}


class Block {
    List requests;
    int blockSize; //minutes
    int blockStartTime;

    Block(int bS, int bst ) {
       blockSize = bs;
       blockStartTime = bst;
    }

    add(OnlineRequest req) {
        requests.add(req);
    }

    getFreeTime() {
        sum = 0;
        foreach (OnlineRequest req in requests) {
            sum += req.Duration;
        }
        return blockSize - sum;
    }

    getStartTime(OnlineRequest or) {
        sum = 0;
        foreach (OnlineRequest req in requests) {
            if ( req = or ) {
                return sum + blockStartTime;
            }
            sum += req.Duration;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```